# Sharepoint column split - common and different

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a number of pages in Sharepoint - one for each country. I want my left hand column to be the same for each country (for global announcements), and the right hand column to be different for each country (for local announcements). I am using Sharepoint 2010.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on what "pages" mean in this context. Possibilites are:

1. Publishing pages - most likely you also have some columns enabling
   clasification of a Page as belonging to a Country. in this situation
   you could maybe rely on the regular Current Navigation to store
   links which shall be the same for all announcements. As for the
   right-hand navigation i would see maybe a simple Web Part which
   could rely on the "page filter" web part to read the Country value
   and pass as parameter to filter other web parts on the right-side,
   such as Data-View / XSLT List Views. The major question that remains
   is: What kind of information you want on Left/Right. One other
   alternative is to rely on Page Layouts to include a Right-Section
   with Summary links/Web-Part, plus the left-side quick launch (=
   current navigation) untouched.
2. If you are using regular Wiki Pages or Web part pages, it shall be more of a manual operation as you don't get to use the contextual filter web part, but rather you would need to setup anything on the site manually.